# Cloudflare Terraform Group Rules

Tags: terraform, devops, cloudflare, cloudflare-zero-trust

I am encountering what appears to be a cloudflare module limitation and want to see if anyone else has overcome this headache. I have a series of pre-existing Cloudflare Zero Trust groups that I want to associate a rule which defined with any email allowed ending in example.com, as well as adding existing Zero Trust application as follows:

```
      variable "groups" {
      default = [{ name = "Cloudflare-Group-1", 
      id = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" 
      application_ids = [
        "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",

      resource "cloudflare_access_rule" "email_rule" {
      zone_id = local.zone_id
      mode = "allow"
      configuration {
        target = "group"
        value = var.groups[0].id
        include {
          email_domain {
            value = "example.com"
          }
        }

      resource "cloudflare_access_application" "groups_applications" {
      count = length(var.groups) * length(var.groups[count.index].application_ids)
      zone_id  = local.zone_id
      group_id = var.groups[count.index].id
      app_id   = var.groups[count.index].application_ids[count.index % length(var.groups[count.index].application_ids)]
    }
```

However there doesn't appear to be an includes option in Terraform for email ending with "value" unlike the option available in the UI:

[image]

Comment: Looks like I worked out how to associate a rule with a cloudflare ZTA group with the module, however it wouldn't work with an existing group: resource "cloudflare_access_group" "example" {
  account_id = "f037e56e89293a057740de681ac9abbe"
  name       = "staging group"

  include {
    email = ["test@example.com"]
  }
}